# How come all USB cables are not equivalent?

Tags: usb, cable

It appears that not all USB cables (one end: USB, the other end - Micro-USB) are created equal: some can only charge devices (e.g., cell phones, e-readers), others can also sync them.

1. Are there just 2 kinds? What's the background?
2. How do I tell one kind from the other without plugging the device?

Comment: related: [How can USB extension cords affect of USB charging?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/93041/7036)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the amount of wires in the cable. Charging-only cables just have two wires in them: power (+5V) and ground. These are often thicker than usual to accomodate the higher charging currents available today (2A+). Needless to say, with just power connected you cannot transfer any data over such a cable.

Sync cables - like any other USB cable - have all four wires implemented: Power, ground and two data lines (D+ and D-, a differential pair). These are usually, but not always, thinner than charging cables and usually designed for currents up to 900mA.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any markings on the cables which identify which kind they are?

Comment: There is no universally agreed upon logo that distinguishes them, but charging-only cables usually have an identifying mark on the micro USB-end - e.g. my charging cables have a 'B' on the molding - whereas data cables have the USB logo on both ends.